# Logic proof need help

Tags: logic

I do not know how to conclude this proof, I cannot put the "code" here so I have to attach an image. Please help
[image]

Comment: Can you please describe in words what you cannot prove, and what you have proven so far? It looks like you're finished - it looks like you're trying to prove that $E$ holds given your four premises, and it looks like you succeed at proving that. Are you trying to use a specific program to code this?

Comment: I need it to go all "+" to prove this, and I just figured line 17out, but I do not know how I should write the final conclusion on line 18

Comment: I suspect you're not supposed to be "indenting" as often as you do, although I don't know what the indenting means. I think you need to have $A$ as a "non-indented" statement after $-M$.

Comment: indenting means subproofs, and -- divides two different parts of subproofs

Comment: Try it again without using subproofs. They'll only get in your way unless you need to do something specific, like a case-bash or a proof by contradiction.

Comment: making an assumption must have indent

Comment: Do you have a link to the theorem prover you are using? Is it accessible by everybody?

Comment: You don't need or want to assume $M$, $C$ or $E$. You should prove them instead.

Answer (score 1):

You *mostly* have it.

Firstly, you may use explosion ($\mathsf X$) to *immediately* derive $E$ from the assumed $M$.

Secondly the derivation of $E$ from $A$ is not irrelevant, it just should not be placed inside *that* subproof, but in a second subproof on the base level, so another disjunction elimination is set up to derive $E$ there.

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}
\fitch{~~1.~C\lor E\\~~2.~A\lor M\\~~3.~A\to\lnot C\\~~4.~\lnot S\land\lnot M}{~~5.~\lnot S\hspace{12ex}{\land}\mathsf E~4\\~~6.~\lnot M\hspace{11.5ex}{\land}\mathsf E~4\\[1ex]\fitch{~~7.~M}{~~8.~\bot\hspace{9ex}\lnot\mathsf E~7,6\\~~9.~E\hspace{10ex}\mathsf{X}~8}\\[1ex]\fitch{10.~A}{11.~\lnot C\hspace{9ex}{\to}\mathsf E~10,3\\\fitch{12.~C}{13.~\bot\hspace{8ex}\lnot\mathsf E~12,11\\14.~E\hspace{10ex}\mathsf X~13}\\\fitch{15.~E}{}\\16.~E\hspace{12ex}{\lor}\mathsf E~1,12{-}14,15{-}15}\\[1ex]17.~E\hspace{16ex}{\lor}\mathsf E~2,10{-}16,7{-}9}$